# Configure IPv6 DNS server via DHCP in LXC container

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, lxc, resolv.conf

I have an LXC container created and started as follows:

```bash
sudo lxc-create -t debian -n mylxc -- --release bullseye
sudo lxc-start -n mylxc
sudo lxc-attach -n mylxc
```

On the LXC host I have a DHCP server running which provides IPv4 and IPv6 IP addresses and announces IPv4 and IPv6 DNS servers.

The LXC correctly gets both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address. It adds only the IPv4 DNS server to `/etc/resolv.conf`, though.

How can I get my LXC container to correctly receive the IPv6 DNS server via DHCP?

Comment: Are the IPv6 addresses obtained through DHCPv6

Comment: I am not sure, actually. How do I know this? DHCP and DNS are served via `dnsmasq` on the LXC host machine.

Comment: but how are you getting IPv**6** addresses - I didn't think dnsmasq did DHCPv6

Comment: Hmm, I actually thought `dnsmasq` would serve these. Why do you assume it doesn't serve them? I actually get useful IPv6 addresses on my devices and there is no other DHCP server running in my network. I am an IPv6 newbie, though, so I might overlook something.

Comment: Could be getting the IPv6 using SLAAC, does your router send Router Advertisements (RA)

Comment: I think dnsmasq can deal with IPv6, if you set it up to do so of course

Comment: I see, I will check that, thanks. I have `dhcp-option=option6:dns-server,<ms-ipv6-dns-address>` in my LXC host's `dnsmasq.conf`, though. IOT-devices within my network correctly receive the IPv6 DNS server, so I assumed from the server-side everything is configured correctly.

Comment: yeah, sorry for the bum steer about dnsmasq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145889/discussion-between-carlfriedrich-and-jaromanda-x).